# Access Form - New field, unwanted focus

Tags: ms-access-2007

I went in to modify a legacy MS Access (2007) form. I added a couple of fields, now when I try to open the form the new field always gets the focus, and it even interrupts the form_load event from firing until I hit a key. I have set the 'tab sto' properties to 'no' but to no avail. Help.

Answer (score 0):

How about in your Form_Load event you set where you want the focus to be.
i.e. Me.txtWhereIWantToBe.SetFocus